# Move back the cursor after a "cw" command

Tags: cursor-movement, replace

I use quite a lot `cw` to change a word. I put the cursor on the start of the word, then `cw` followed by the new word and then `<esc>`.

So far, so good. My problem is that after that the cursor is at the end of the (new) word. I know I can move back with `b`, but it's possible to define a modified version of `cw` so that the movement is automatic at the end of the insert?

Comment: By the way, I discovered that that was a case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) --- what I really want here is to learn about `ciw` (change inner word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `:help :map-expression` that defines a fire-once autocmd on `InsertLeave` (i.e. when you're done with the change) to move back the cursor. I've used `` `[; `` instead of the `b` motion, because that also handles multiple inserted words. Since I wouldn't want to override `cw`, I've chosen `c,w`:

```
function! ToStartOfChange()
    augroup ToStartOfChange
        autocmd ToStartOfChange InsertLeave * execute 'normal! g`[' | autocmd! ToStartOfChange
    augroup END
    return 'cw'
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> c,w ToStartOfChange()
```

Comment: +1 and thanks, it works; but it has a problem: if I repeat the change after the first one with `.` the "going back" is not repeated. I am accepting the answer because I really did not specify that thing...

Comment: You need to use the [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136) plugin to make repeat work. Unfortunately, that requires some more boilerplate code, like `<Plug>` mappings.